# Sending email securely to an SMS service

Tags: php, email

I am looking into sending SMS through PHP to certain people via an SMS service called cmsms.dk.

The way it is done is that I send an email to their mail address like this:
`4512345678.abcd1defg@cpsms.dk` and the content of the mail is sent as a SMS to the number. The first part is the number, then the access code associated with this account and lastly the SMS provider's mail address.

Now my concern is that information sent is something i would like to keep away from unwanted eyes.

The phone number is what it is but the code part is something I really don't like other to see (in this case `abcd1defg`)

So my question is: when I send a mail with PHP, how safe is this mail from interception? Also, is there a way I can safely send a mail to their email without having to worry that the password might get intercepted and abused?

Comment: I would guess that the cmsms.dk service will be able to read the content of your sms anyway, as long as you don't encryt it...

Comment: Email is sent as unencrypted plain text over the public internet so should always be considered to be open to interception. Even if you somehow encrypt the content, the headers have to be plain text for it to work. It makes no difference what programming language you use to send it.

Comment: So what your saying is, I am at the mercy of whom ever intercepts the mail and peels out the code and starts using it them self?

Comment: What I am saying is that email is not safe. If you want safety then you should see if they offer an API or other method except email.

Comment: @Anigel Email **MAY BE** safe(r) when send submitted over encrypted connections: SMTPS (SMTP over SSL on port 465) or via ESMTP connection with STARTTLS issued (start encryption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cpsms.dk mail server (MX=>cpsms.dk) seems to offer encryption (It lists STARTTLS esmtp extension).
It also seems to have started accepting SMTPS (SMTP over SSL on port 465).

---

So you may choose one of the following options:

- try php code supporting SMTPS (SMTP over SSL) [with SSL certificates check]
- try php code supporting STARTTLS in a "must be started" way [with SSL certificates check]
- send your mails via local mail/MTA server configured to enforce encrypted connection to cpsms.dk. On Unix/Linux Sendmail can be configured to enforce STARTTLS to selected destinations.